# How to embed shiny app on SharePoint with Iframe tag

Tags: r, iframe, sharepoint, shiny

I have a very simple app showing some data. 
How do you embed this in a SharePoint site using using iframe ?
or is there an easier way to do this ?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(readr)

PRTypeCount <- read_csv("H:/SP/PRTypeCount.txt")



ui <- navbarPage(
title = 'PRTypeCount',
tabPanel('PRTypeCount', DT::dataTableOutput('PRTypeCount')))

server<-function(input, output) {

output$PRTypeCount <- DT::renderDataTable(
DT::datatable(PRTypeCount, options = list(pageLength = 25))
)

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Do you have your app running on a shiny server or shinyapps.io?

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment. I'm not familiar with shinny. no, I don't have it on a actual server.
no, I don't have it on shinyapps.io

Comment: Yes.  Shiny apps must be run on a server or you can use the shinyapps.io sever.

Comment: If you just want to publish a datatable to SharePoint you can use r makrdown easily.

Comment: How do I do that ??

Comment: Which version of SharePoint do you have?

Comment: I have SharePoint Designer 2010. Also they want a dashboard, I don't know if this allows for customization and display of multiple things like shiny app

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions or if the steps are not clear.

Comment: they're clear, I'm just bad. Thanks! but yea I'll ask if I cant figure something out

Answer (score 4):

If you do not have a shiny server your best bet is probably the flexdashboard package or making individual components and arranging them in SharePoint designer.  Here is a quick example, you will be somewhat limited with interactivity as compared to shiny -- there are some things you can do with plotly, ggiraph, and some other packages. For many use cases this can be perfectly adequate:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```

Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}
DT::datatable(iris)
```

Column {data-width=350}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart B

```{r}

hist(iris$Sepal.Length)

```

### Chart C

```{r}
plot(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width)

```
````

Once you knit this rmd file to html.  You make can make a copy of the HTML file and change the extension to .aspx.

Then you can put this .aspx file in in a document library.

Then add a page viewer web part where you want the content displayed, linking it to the .aspx file in the document library.

Comment: I made a html by knit to flex_dashboard. it opens and shows the table in R Studio, but when I open it in browser, it doesn't show anything

Comment: Does the file work in chrome?  If you are only having issues in IE, is the file stored on a shared drive?  In which case IE opens the file in compatibility mode which you would need to disable, or override.

Comment: It doesn't show in IE but works fine in other browsers. I don't see a web part called web content web part.. could it be named something else in my version or should I try a different web part?

Comment: I'm trying with just the content editor web apart. I have the aspx 'linked' to it .. however on the site it just shows the url of the aspx..   I don't know SharePoint well either ..

Comment: I'm sorry I should have said a "page viewer web part"